# How to create a database in cpanel using codignter using migrations

Tags: codeigniter, cpanel, dbforge

I am using dbForge to create a dynamic database in cPanel using CodeIgnter, and I'm getting this error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 1044
>
> Access denied for user '************'@'localhost' to database 'informsa_inform_sap_10000'
>
> CREATE DATABASE `informsa_inform_sap_10000` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

What does it mean?

Comment: Are you sure you have appropriate db user and corresponding privileges for the catalog you are accessing?

Comment: Enter the correct db credentials (of your cpanel) in your database config file.

Comment: yeh. I used the correct credentials of the cpanel and that user have all privileges including create

Answer (score 0):

you need to give privileges to the database user you created;
cpanel / database users can go and edit privileges.

or create a new database **user and define all privileges**